# Airflow - Generating tasks dynamically from BigQuery, but tasks are run repeatedly before previous finishes

Tags: python, google-bigquery, airflow, google-cloud-composer

**Context**

I'm trying to build an ingestion pipeline on Google Cloud Platform using Composer, DataProc and BigQuery. I have a table in BigQuery which contains records of data source and its relevant file. So if there are 5 files which I need to ingest, I have 5 records in the BigQuery table. Tomorrow it could be a different number of files. Hence, I thought about building tasks dynamically within my DAG.

The high level design is as follows:

- Execute a function to fetch data from BigQuery as a Pandas dataframe (or dict, either is fine)
- Iterate over the dataframe
- For each row in the dataframe, create a DataProcSparkOperator with details about the file and corresponding args

This setup runs fine. I can see my DAG and all dynamically generated tasks in Airflow UI.

Edit: Just adding few more details. The BigQuery table will have less than 25 records so querying the table is not concern. Querying the table every 30 seconds is. Secondly, I only need this DAG to run once every 4 hours or so. I do not intend to keep my composer running for that time. All I need every 4 hours is to boot Composer, run the DAG **once** to process all available files and then shut down.

**The problem**

While these DataProc tasks are executing, after about a couple of minutes Airflow refreshes the DAG and runs the same set of tasks again. In DataProc Jobs console, I see 2 (sometimes 3) instances of the same task in running state. This is undesirable.

**What I have tried**

I have set `retries=0` at the task level and on the DAG I have set `catchup=False`, `max_active_runs=1`, and `schedule_interval='@once'`. Default arguments for the DAG also have `retries=0`.

I think the issue is because the part where I am pulling records from BigQuery is part of an ordinary function, rather than being a task in itself. The reason I have not put that in a task is because I couldn't find a solution to pass fetched result from BigQuery into subsequent tasks where I have to loop over them.

I tried calling a PythonOperator and executing `Variable.set("df", df)` inside it in the hope that I can loop over `Variable.get("df")` but that didn't work out either.

Sharing relevant code below.

```
def fetch_pending_files_from_bq():
    # fetch records from BigQuery and return as dataframe

default_args = {
    'start_date': yesterday,
    'default_timezone': 'utc',
    'retries': 0
}

dag = DAG(
    dagid,
    default_args=default_args,
    catchup=False,
    max_active_runs=1,
    description='DAG to ingest data',
    schedule_interval='@once'
)

start_dag = DummyOperator(task_id="start_dag", dag=dag)
end_dag = DummyOperator(task_id="end_dag", dag=dag)

pending_files_df = fetch_pending_files_from_bq()

for index, row in pending_files_df.iterrows():
    task = DataProcSparkOperator(
        dag=dag,
        task_id=row["file_name"],
        arguments=dataproc_args,
        region="us-east1",
        job_name="job_{}".format(task_id),
        dataproc_spark_jars=dataproc_jars,
        ....
        ....
    )

    task.set_upstream(start_dag)
    task.set_downstream(end_dag)
```

I get the orchestration that I want, the only issue is my DataProc jobs getting re-run automatically.

Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: Airflow tasks should be as static as possible (slowly changing is OK). Creating tasks from db table which updates constantly isn't a good idea. it will also create a havey loading on your db connection. Specifically for BigQuery this may means you also pay a lot of money. The  `fetch_pending_files_from_bq` function is executed every 30 seconds (default of `min_file_process_interval` ) so you are querying BigQuery every 30 seconds. Depends on the scale of data that you scan this may resulted in a high bill.

Comment: @Elad in terms of BigQuery this table will have less than 25 records so the cost of queries wouldn't be too much. Also I must add that I will probably execute this DAG once every 3-4 hours only.
It's correct though that I don't want to query BQ every 30 secs. What other option do I have? Even if I query BQ and write results to disk and then loop over that file, won't that writing process be triggered every 30 secs too?

Comment: probably you will need to have another ETL exporting BQ to storage. In any case this line is strange `job_name="job_{}".format(task_id)` task_id is not a defined parameter. Are you sure thats your real code? Please also provide images/logs that shows the problem you described of "unrecognized" tasks appearing.

Comment: @Elad - this is my code, but it's not the full code since I cannot post it publicly. `task_id` is indeed a valid parameter, and the code works fine. Let me try to grab some screenshots when I run it today.

Comment: While diving deeper into the design, I realized that `fetch_pending_files_from_bq` is not a task so it gets executed each time the dag is refreshed. That led to multiple queries, and also caused the unexpected creation of duplicate tasks. Hence I dropped this design. I was able to fix this using subdags. The first subdag reads from BQ and writes to GCS. The second subdag reads the file from GCS and creates tasks dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While diving deeper into the design, I realized that fetch_pending_files_from_bq is not a task so it gets executed each time the dag is refreshed. That led to multiple queries, and also caused the unexpected creation of duplicate tasks. Hence I dropped this design.

I was able to fix this using subdags. The first subdag reads from BQ and writes to GCS. The second subdag reads the file from GCS and creates tasks dynamically.